# view handler date not working

Tags: 7, views, hooks

I am creating views handler for date in `hook_views_data`. All other fields working fine but date. I am assigning `views_handler_field_date` and `views_handler_filter_date` in fields and filter respectively.

The problem is that when I select date field in views I get empty response as well as got bunch of errors.

Comment: edit with your code please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what your code looks like, but my suggestion is to use custom handler if  the core is not working. I used custom handler in almost all my projects if I get any issue in core handler. Example is:

```
/**
 * A handler to display dates as just the time if today, otherwise as time and date.
 *
 * @ingroup views_field_handlers
 */
class views_handler_cusom_field_date extends views_handler_field_date {

  function options_form(&$form, &$form_state) {
    parent::options_form($form, $form_state);
    $form['date_format']['#options']['example_custom'] = t('My custom format');
  }  

  function render($values) {
    $format = $this->options['date_format'];
    $value = $values->{$this->field_alias};
    // check for our custom format
    if ($format == 'example_custom') {
      // check to see whether value is whithin today range
      $timezone = new DateTimeZone("Australia/Melbourne"); 
      $date = new DateTime();
      $date->setTimezone($timezone);
      $today = strtotime($date->format('Y-m-d 00:00:00'));
      if ($value >= $today) {
        // this value is still within today
        return format_date($value, 'custom', 'g:i A');
      }
      else {
        // this value is older than today
        return format_date($value, 'custom', 'j M Y g:i A');      
      }
    }
    // otherwise render the date using the normal date handler
    else {
      return parent::render($values);
    }
  }

}
```

And then call this custom handler in your date field

```
'date' => array(      
           'title' => t('Date'),

           'field' => array(
              'handler'=> 'views_handler_cusom_field_date'
              'click sortable' => TRUE,
           ),
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. I researched on the forum and created a custom handler and bypassed all other logic just rendered the date in my format and it solved the problem